# Pybind11: How to create bindings for a function that takes in a struct as an argument?

Tags: c++, pybind11

Please see below C++ code that I am trying to create python bindings for

```
struct Config {
  int a;
  int b;
};

void myfunction(const Config &config);
```

Here is what I have so far,

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
  py::class_<Config>(m, "Config")
    .def_readwrite("a", &Config::a)
    .def_readwrite("b", &Config::b);

  m.def("myfunction", &myfunction);
}
```

This compiles, but when I attempt to call the python bindings in python,

```
import example

config = example.Config;
config.a = 1;
config.b = 2;

example.myfunction(config)
```

I got the below error

```
TypeError: myfunction(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: example.Config) -> None

Invoked with: <class 'example.Config'>
```

Can someone let me know what is the right way to create python bindings for a function that takes in a struct as an argument?

Comment: Typo: `config = example.Config;` -> `config = example.Config()`?

Comment: @eyllanesc pretty sure it's not, if I did what you suggested, `TypeError: example.Config: No constructor defined!`

Comment: Why don't you declare a default constructor and associate it with py::init?

Comment: @eyllanesc has provided the answer to the issue as posted (unfortunately as a comment). You pass a class instead of an instance (`Invoked with: <class 'example.Config'>` gives a strong hint of this). Issues with declaring a default constructor sound like a separate issue. But providing the default constructor and then getting the _same_ error, well, code to reproduce that would be useful, because it sounds unlikely.

Comment: @eyllanesc you are right, I got it to work with your hint. If you write up an answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @user3667089 Better you post the answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted by @eyllanesc, the problem will be solved by adding a default constructor:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
  py::class_<Config>(m, "Config")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def_readwrite("a", &Config::a)
    .def_readwrite("b", &Config::b);

  m.def("myfunction", &myfunction);
}
```

```
import example

config = example.Config();
config.a = 1;
config.b = 2;

example.myfunction(config)
```